# How to modify JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I update a value at a specific index in the following multi dimensional JSON array?

I would like to update the value of `background-image` placed inside the `footer_logo` node.

```
{
    "Machine1": {
        "sidebar_inner": {
            "img": "img/pill.png",
            "background-color": "#ffffff",
            "side_logo": {
                "background-image": "../footer_logo.png"
            }
        },
        "lb_footer": {
            "img": "img/bin.png",
            "footer_logo": {
                "background-image": "..img/footer_logo.png"
            }
        },
        "machine_stand": {
            "img": "img/machine_stand.png"
        },
        "side": {
            "backgroundcolor": "#ccc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to describe your question clearly, right now it is unclear and vague.

Comment: `obj[findex][sindex][tindex] = myvalue`

Comment: Being pedantic: This isn't a JSON array, it's a JS object, similar to a hash map in other languages.

Comment: @AyazShakoor, please see my answer for the background-image footer_logo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update nested values, you would chain keys (indexes are for arrays) together to find the appropriate value.

Here's the code, formatted for easy consumption:

```
var obj = {"Machine1": {
    "sidebar_inner": {
        "img": "img/pill.png",
        "background-color": "#ffffff",
        "side_logo": {
            "background-image": "../footer_logo.png"
        }
    },
    "lb_footer": {
        "img": "img/bin.png",
        "footer_logo": {
            "background-image": "..img/footer_logo.png"
        }
    },
    "machine_stand": { 
        "img": "img/machine_stand.png"
    }, 
    "side": {
        "backgroundcolor":"#ccc"
    }
}}
```

### Examples

To update "footer_logo"'s background image: `obj.Machine1.lb_footer,footer_logo.background-image = "something new";`

To update "machine_stand's" img:

```
obj.machine_stand.img = "new/link.jpg";
// or use 'bracket notation', it's the same thing
obj['machine_stand']['img'] = "new/link.jpg"
```

Answer (score 3):

I've added a jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cts89w6h/3/). It's prety simple, take a look at the code below.

```
var myJson = {
        "Machine1": {
            "sidebar_inner": {
                "img": "img/pill.png",
                "background-color": "#ffffff",
                "side_logo": {
                    "background-image": "../footer_logo.png"
                }
            },
            "lb_footer": {
                "img": "img/bin.png",
                "footer_logo": {
                    "background-image": "..img/footer_logo.png"
                }
            },
            "machine_stand": {
                "img": "img/machine_stand.png"
            },
            "side": {
                "backgroundcolor": "#ccc"
            }
        }
    };

    myJson.Machine1.lb_footer.footer_logo['background-image'] = 'New value.';

    alert(myJson.Machine1.lb_footer.footer_logo['background-image']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. A working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m31f1bft/)

```
    var json= '{"Machine1":{"sidebar_inner":{"img":"img\/pill.png","background-color":"#ffffff","side_logo":{"background-image":"..\/footer_logo.png"}},"lb_footer":{"img":"img\/bin.png","footer_logo":{"background-image":"..img\/footer_logo.png"}},"machine_stand":{"img":"img\/machine_stand.png"},"side":{"backgroundcolor":"#ccc"}}}';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
    jsonObj.Machine1.lb_footer.footer_logo['background-image'] = 'abc';
```

Comment: Why put the data first in a string and then parse it?

Comment: Do not understand. First, for demonstration, second, if you do not parse it, you can not access it as an object. Or do you meant, why not inject it directly in the parse the string?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by directly in the parse the string. But you could omit the quotes and then you don't need to parse. Sew the other answers.

Comment: Oh, I see. I do it, because I was not sure, is this coming from an AJAX, or is this in javascript. I've just want to demonstrate, what if it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr["Machine1"]["lb_footer"]["footer_logo"]["background-image"] = mynewvalue;
```

Comment: `lb_footer` is twice, and no `footer_logo`